# Building Ruby from source on Mac, not working

Tags: ruby, upgrade

I'm trying to build Ruby 1.9.2 from source on Snow Leopard and I keep getting this error:

```
readline.c: In function ‘username_completion_proc_call’:
readline.c:1292: error: ‘username_completion_function’ undeclared (first use in this function)
readline.c:1292: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
readline.c:1292: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [readline.o] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

I am basing it off of [this tutorial](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard) and the error comes when I do the `make` command.

I already have 1.8.7 installed, but want to upgrade to the latest and have not found a reliable, simple way to do it yet.

Comment: Below I was told to try out RVM to get around this issue.  When trying to install it via RVM I get an error and when I check the log it is the exact same error as this post.  So RVM is not the answer.

Comment: I think the problem is you don't have the readline development package installed. RVM has a separate page talking about it; There's a link in my answer below, which will help when using RVM.

Comment: Have you tried updating your [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Availability)?

Comment: Also, that tutorial isn't quite accurate for Ruby 1.9+. Rubygems is now a part of Ruby in 1.9+. [This](http://bparanj.blogspot.com/2010/06/installing-ruby-191-on-snow-leopard.html) looks like a better tutorial or [this](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/07/08/installing-ruby-1-9-2-with-rvm-on-snow-leopard/) except the current version of Ruby 1.9.2 is 1.9.2-p136.

Comment: @Tin Man, that 2nd link almost got me there but I'm still working through some errors that he didn't have, but thank you very much for getting me this far!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to upgrade to the latest version of Ruby on Snow Leopard is to use [RVM (The Ruby Version Manager)](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't upgraded your version of XCode that came on the DVD, then do so from [Apple's Developer site](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/). XCode on the DVD has some errors. You have to register, but it's free.

Snow Leopard has 1.8.7 installed, but that is for Apple's use; They install code that actually uses Ruby and messing with their Ruby or installed code could break things. You might not know something broke for a while, until things don't work quite right, so it's better to leave their install alone and put one in for your own use.

As said by other answers, [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) is a great way to install Ruby for your own use. You don't need to install into `/usr/local/bin` and you definitely don't want to overwrite the Ruby in `/usr/bin`. RVM deals with this by installing into `~/.rvm`. You can have multiple Rubies installed, along with the gems associated with a Ruby, create sets of gems, copy them around, remove or recompile a particular Ruby, or blow it all away without affecting the Apple installed Rubyies. RVM is actively developed and updates often, and the author is very responsive to questions.

RVM has a page dealing with the [readline issues](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/). It is specific to dealing with RVM but might help if you want to forego using RVM and go with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) its by far the easiest way to get ruby compiled and has many other benefits.

Comment: The whole point of upgrading was so that I could work with MacRuby, which is already installed, but now RVM says if I want to use MacRuby I have to install "LLVM" first, so do I now need to uninstall MacRuby, then install LLVM, then reinstall MacRuby?

Comment: You only need to install LLVM with RVM if you want the latest development snapshots of MacRuby development versions from HEAD, otherwise "rvm install macruby" will install it and make it available to you in one command. So do you want Ruby 1.9.2, or MacRuby, or both?